# Having Excel return a date, based on a text based cell input

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, lookup

I have a self made workbook in excel for by work. On one sheet (Lets call it Sheet 1) I list our main suppliers, their address, how many items we have purchased and total spent.

Eg. Supplier 1, Address, #Items purchased, Total

On a seperate sheet (Sheet 2) in the same workbook I have a full order breakdown (Date, Supplier, Client, Amount, Items etc) for about 10 years worth of data (Approx 1000 rows of data).

Eg. Order Date, Client, Sales Order Number, Supplier, Item, Cost, etc.

In sheet 1, I want it to automatically display the date of the most recent order associated with that supplier based on the info from sheet 2.
So it will look something like this:

Eg. Supplier 1. Address, #Items purchased, Total, (Date from recent order on sheet 2)

I think I need to use either a LOOKUP, or INDEX, or MATCH or a combination of all three.

All solutions I have found online deal with a range of dates, I want this to have one specific date shown associated with that specific supplier.
Un fortunately I cannot provide pictures as the data is sensitive. Can anyone help?

Edit: I do not know if this will help but to calculate the cost of certain items in the workbook I have used this formula: =LOOKUP(MATCH(N2,Calcs!B$1:B$147,0),Calcs!A$1:A$147,Calcs!C$1:C$147)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the version of Excel you would use one of the following:

2007 or earlier this Array Formula:

```
=MAX(IF('Sheet2'!$D$1:$D$100=A2,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$100))
```

It is an Array so Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode.

2010 or later:

```
=Aggregate(14,6,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$100/('Sheet2'!$D$1:$D$100=A2),1)
```

If you have the most current Excel with office 365 or are using the online version then:

```
=MAXIFS('Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$100,'Sheet2'!$D$1:$D$100,A2)
```

Comment: I did make this using excel 03 but am now using excel 16, Also apologies for lack of knowledge but what is Aggregate?

Comment: Aggregate will not work in 2003, but it is an aggregate of formulas, that allows arrays without the need of CSE.  The first criterion`14` is for Large().  The second `6` tells it to ignore errors, The third creates and array of numbers and errors, the errors get ignored.  The last `1` tells the formula you want the 1st largest or max.

Comment: Just tried the aggregate and it worked perfectly, I assume that this will auto-update as I go along. I've been racking my head on how to get Lookup to work with this. Many thanks.

Comment: Have now used this for a customer tab I have just added, once again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following array formula?

```
=MAX(IF($D$2:$D$7=$A2,$E$2:$E$7,0))
```

[image]

Note you can use Evaluate formula to see how it works, and you need to press ctrl+shift+enter after entering the formula to get the curly brackets at each end that change behaviour to an array forula.

Regards,

James

Comment: Hi James, I have not, but I will add it into my 'Calculations' Tab and I will play around with it later.

Comment: I have tried using this formual but as my data is in two seperate heets I cannot use the dollar signs to reference the cells for some reason.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I can't reproduce this - my formula moving the data to sheet 2 is as follows: {=MAX(IF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7=$A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$7,0))}. Is your data on the second sheet in a table? (Insert -> Table)

Comment: To answer your question, yes, I have two tables, one in Sheet 1 where I want the dates to appear and the main raw data in Sheet 2. I will try again at some point today and update you.

Comment: Thanks for your commitment Matthew, all the best. James